# Misalignment in LyX document on exporting to PDF

Tags: formatting, lyx

Whenever I render my lyx documents, I get a misalignment in the text like so:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! Please post a minimal example .lyx file and ideally .tex file as well. Please read here for more information: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Answer (score 1):

There are no any misalignment here, but ...

1. A header that should be a `Subsection*`,  but really is  `Standard` text in bold, so it is formatted as any other paragraph (wrong indentation of 15 pt, wrong lack of vertical spacing after the header).
2. Then a first sentence broken into three paragraphs at unexpected points by abuse of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, trying to do manual breaks of the lines, I guess. and finally two sentences in another paragraph.

So, what you see is a total of 5 paragraphs,  perfectly indented 15pt in the first line and aligned with both margins in the following lines. By default, the first line of the paragraphs  is indented to identify where each paragraph begins (except under the true titles in some languages, where is always clear the start of the first paragraph).

Note line breaks within a paragraph usually are automatic, and rarely you will need to specify manual line breaks with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone in plain LyX text is not a line break, but the end of a  paragraph (= line break,plus insert the `\parskip` vertical space and   `\parindent` horizontal space in the next line, that by default are 0pt and 15pt respectively).

If you don't want this indentation, but mark the beginning of the paragraphs with some vertical space, go to menu <kbd>Document</kbd> → <kbd>Settings...</kbd> → <kbd>Text layout</kbd> → **`Paragraph separation`** and set `Indentation` and `Vertical space` properly.

To avoid the indentation only in one paragraph (not in the whole document) → mouse right-click on the text → <kbd>Paragraph settings...</kbd>  → Uncheck `Indent Paragraph`